# Headers are not populating in SSRS report while exporting CSV

Tags: sql, oracle

Headers are wrongly populating while exporting SSRS report into CSV, instead of alias names it gives SQL column names, am using SSDT 2015 to generate the reports

Comment: Hi @Anil and welcome to SO! Please share some code and/or steps that you have taken in order for people help you resolve your issue.

Comment: Does SSRS work with Oracle?

Comment: @Jarlh, yes Generating reports from Oracle through SSRS

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I worked with SSRS, but if I remember correctly SSRS uses the "Name" property of the field when doing a CSV export. If you examine the Property of each field (right-click on the field and choose Properties), the value listed under "Name" is most likely your field name, not your header value.

You just need to update the "Name" value to match the header name for each field, then when exporting it should match the header.